# Searching dictionary works find with hard coded variable, but otherwise crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have the following code to search the following dictionary:

```
//NSString *knownObject = @"3:40 am";
NSArray *temp = [itemDict allKeysForObject:knownObject];
NSString *key = [temp objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"prayer: %@", key);
```

Dict:

```
{
    asr = "4:23 pm";
    dhuhr = "12:02 pm";
    fajr = "1:16 am";
    isha = "10:47 pm";
    maghrib = "8:24 pm";
    shurooq = "3:40 am";
}
```

When running the first line, it correctly returns "shurooq". However, when I use my variable:

```
    NSArray *temp = [itemDict allKeysForObject:nextPrayerTime];
```

The log output of `nextPrayerTime` is simply `3:40 am` as expected.

Why is this not working?

Many thanks!

Comment: what is you actually want??

Comment: Replace find with fine in your title. Also confirm that your code is crashing when you use "nextPrayerTime" as parameter to allKeysForObject. Can you show the code you are using to create nextPrayerTime?

Comment: It is probably crashing at this line [temp objectAtIndex:0] post your full code including what is in nextprayertime

Comment: Most likely "nextPrayerTime" is not quite equal to the key in your dict.  "temp" comes back with zero entries, and the objectAtIndex therefore craps on it.

Comment: Hint, do `NSLog(@"They're %s", ([nextPrayerTime isEqualToString:knownObject] ? "EQUAL" : "NOT EQUAL");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the value of `nextPrayerTime`, if `itemDict` contain any object same as `nextPrayerTime` then  `[itemDict allKeysForObject:nextPrayerTime];` will return an array of keys otherwise it will return empty array.

In your current case anyhow you get an empty array but when you try to access `[temp objectAtIndex:0]` then compiler couldn't find any object and it gets an array out of bound exception and this cause the crash of your app....

To overcome this exception you should check the count of objects in array...

```
NSArray *temp = [itemDict allKeysForObject: nextPrayerTime];
if([temp count] > 0) {
    NSString *key = [temp objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"prayer: %@", key);
} else
    NSLog(@"NO Object Found");
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of `nextPrayerTime`?

According to the docs, `allKeysForObject:` returns

> A new array containing the keys corresponding to all occurrences of anObject in the dictionary. If no object matching anObject is found, returns an empty array.

Based on the information given I would guess you are getting back an empty array and when you call `[temp objectAtIndex:0]` you are accessing an index that does not exist and getting an out of bounds exception.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a 100% sure of my answer, but is the method isEqualToString used for comparison of the objects when the object is a NSString?

Otherwise you probably need to compare to the original object in the dictionary (using the same NSString).